# How do i make xticks in a bar graph not be cramped when working with yearly data

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, xticks

I´m getting an issue when trying to do this graph bar and keep getting the same error

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
!pip install wbdata
import wbdata

wbdata.get_source()
wbdata.get_source()

indicador = {'SP.POP.TOTL' : 'Population total', 'SP.POP.GROW':'Population growth'}
pais = ['CRI']
df = wbdata.get_dataframe(indicador, pais)
df['date'] = df.index
pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df.reset_index(drop = True, inplace = True)
df = df[['date','Population total', 'Population growth' ]]

df.iloc[::-1].plot.bar(x = 'date', y = 'Population total', color = 'g')

plt.xticks(df['date'][::10], rotation = 'vertical')

plt.title('Total de población de Costa Rica y crecimiento')
plt.show()
```

the error i keep getting looks like this

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vtgj5.png)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it:

```
df.plot.bar(x = 'date', y = 'Population total', color = 'g')
plt.xticks(ticks = df[::-1].date.iloc[::10].index.array, labels = df.date.iloc[::10])
plt.yticks(ticks = [elem * 1000000 for elem in range(1,6)] , labels = [elem * 1000000 for elem in range(1,6)] )
df2.plot.line(x = 'date', y='Population growth')



plt.title('Total de población de Costa Rica y crecimiento')
plt.xticks(df[::-1].date.iloc[::10].index.array,df.date.iloc[::10])
plt.show()
```